# Async loading table data in ember route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is it possible to async load a table inside a route without a nested route?

From the image below, my url is /cm/ccas. The API call to load the CCAs can be heavy so I wanted to load it asynchronously.

When the page loads and the user searches, I would like to show the index route, an a "loading" template where the table is.

If I add a loading template to the index, it replaces the entire index route template.

I can make it work with a nested route, but then my url becomes /cm/ccas/index/results which seems ... not right.

[image]

I am using a service to make the API call, cannot user Ember.Data because the API and models don't align.

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9080/customermaster/api/ccas/',
    getAll: function () {
        return ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: this.baseUrl
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.map(function(r) {
                    return CCA.create(r);
                });
            });
    },
    getByInitials: function(initials) {
        return ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: this.baseUrl + initials
        }).then(function(response){
            var model = CCA.create(response);

            return model;
        });
    }
});
```

Index Route (above service (ccas) is injected via initializer):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        query: {
            refreshModel: true
        }
    },
    model: function (params) {
        if (!params.query) {
            // no query params, return all
            return this.ccas.getAll();
        }

        // todo: call query function
        return this.ccas.getAll();
    }
});
```

Index Template

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Customer Care Associates</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="data-table-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" {{action "new"}}><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped data-table no-footer" role="grid">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Initials</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {{#each cca in model}}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{cca.initials}}</td>
                                    <td>{{cca.name}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                {{/each}}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Loading & Error substates](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/)

Comment: I've the loading substate working, my problem is that it replaces the entire index template. I am looking for something more fine grained that will replace part of a template, in this case the table.